# Dataweave error "Types `Array` and `Number` can not be compared

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am learning Mulesoft 4 and trying to run a filter on a list of books. In the Transform message, there are no errors and in the preview, the books are filtered by price as expected.

When I run the request in my REST client, I get the following 500 Server Error error. When I remove the filter, I get a successful post in REST. I set a breakpoint on the Transform component and got the error below. How can I fix this?

[Books input payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4TP0.png)

**Detailed error description**

```
INFO  2021-03-27 16:51:32,014 [[MuleRuntime].uber.05: [data-weave-1].data-weave-1Flow.CPU_LITE @6c4cd988] [processor: data-weave-1Flow/processors/0; event: 979d4040-8f46-11eb-8c87-6817296a6b20] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Start upload
ERROR 2021-03-27 16:54:05,959 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [data-weave-1].data-weave-1Flow.CPU_INTENSIVE @744a745c] [processor: ; event: 979d4040-8f46-11eb-8c87-6817296a6b20] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : "Types `Array` and `Number` can not be compared.

6|  book: payload.catalog.*book filter($.price < 10) map ((data, index) -> 
                                       ^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at main (line: 6, column: 37)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
catalog:
{
    book: payload.catalog.*book filter($.price < 10) map ((data, index) -> 
    {
        autor: data.author,
        title: data.title,
        genre: data.genre,
        price: data.price
    })
}".
Element               : data-weave-1Flow/processors/1 @ data-weave-1:data-weave-1.xml:15 (Transform Message)
Element DSL           : <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="f3e0bf40-cf5f-421b-a895-b75fbd5ff58e">
<ee:message>
<ee:set-payload>%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
catalog:
{
    book: payload.catalog.*book filter($.price < 10) map ((data, index) -> 
    {
        autor: data.author,
        title: data.title,
        genre: data.genre,
        price: data.price
    })
}</ee:set-payload>
</ee:message>
</ee:transform>
Error type            : MULE:EXPRESSION
FlowStack             : at data-weave-1Flow(data-weave-1Flow/processors/1 @ data-weave-1:data-weave-1.xml:15 (Transform Message))

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

**Input code**

```
{
  "catalog": {
    "book": [
      {
        "autor": "Knorr, Stefan",
        "title": "Creepy Crawlies",
        "genre": "Horror",
        "price": "4.95"
      },
      {
        "autor": "Randall, Cynthia",
        "title": "Lover Birds",
        "genre": "Romance",
        "price": "4.95"
      },
      {
        "autor": "O'Brien, Tim",
        "title": "MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide",
        "genre": "Computer",
        "price": "36.95"
      },
      {
        "autor": "Corets, Eva",
        "title": "Maeve Ascendant",
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "price": "5.95"
      },
      {
        "autor": "O'Brien, Tim",
        "title": "Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible",
        "genre": "Computer",
        "price": "36.95"
      },
      {
        "autor": "Ralls, Kim",
        "title": "Midnight Rain",
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "price": "5.95"
      },
      {
        "autor": "Corets, Eva",
        "title": "Oberon's Legacy",
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "price": "5.95"
      },
      {
        "autor": "Kress, Peter",
        "title": "Paradox Lost",
        "genre": "Science Fiction",
        "price": "6.95"
      },
      {
        "autor": "Thurman, Paula",
        "title": "Splish Splash",
        "genre": "Romance",
        "price": "4.95"
      },
      {
        "autor": "Corets, Eva",
        "title": "The Sundered Grail",
        "genre": "Fantasy",
        "price": "5.95"
      },
      {
        "autor": "Galos, Mike",
        "title": "Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide",
        "genre": "Computer",
        "price": "49.95"
      },
      {
        "autor": "Gambardella, Matthew",
        "title": "XML Developer's Guide",
        "genre": "Computer",
        "price": "44.95"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a input payload example? Thank you.

Comment: My guess would be that you're either not getting a flat array, so `$.price` is returning an array, or you're getting a data structure where `$.price` really is just an array. Even though preview is correct, preview uses metadata not the actual output. Slap a breakpoint on and debug, then use the evalulate dataweave window to just do `payload.catalog.*book` and see what the structure looks like.

Comment: Also please post the complete error information. Many time it includes some information about the offending data and other insights.

Comment: @aled see detailed error msg above. Michael, it works without the filter. Olamiral see payload link above.

Comment: That's not a payload. That's the structure from metadata. Please add the actual input that causes the error, in text, not a screenshot.

Comment: @aled, i'm not sure what you mean by input. Are you referring to the Body of my POST response in my REST client?

Comment: I mean the actual input to the transformation that throws the error. If that input is the input to the flow -probably your POST body- then yes, the body. However if thereis a previous operation or transformation that altered the payload then you have to find it and share it here.

Comment: The Flow is very simple. It has a Listener, Logger, Transform Msg, & Logger in that order so there's nothing else interfering with the Transform component. See input code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you to get the expected output. The price in the input is a string (since its inside "") and thus the comparison in filter coerces it as a Number prior to comparing it to the limit (10).

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
catalog:
{
    book: (payload.catalog.*book map {
                 temp: $ filter ($.price as Number < 10) map {
                     author:$.autor,
                     title: $.title,
                     genre: $.genre,
                     price: $.price
                 }
                  
    }.temp)[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the answer with the screenshot from Studio:

Script within a Mule app in studio:

[image]

---

Result of the execution of the DW script, for the payload mentioned in the **Assumed Input** section

[image]

===============================================================

I am assuming your input payload looks something like below as if i leave the filter outside i can reproduce the error that you get, attributing to the datatype of the book [].

**Assumed Input**:

```
{

    "catalog": [{
            "a1": "a2",
            "book": [{
                "author": "bac",
                "title": "def",
                "genre": "abc",
                "price": 15
            }, {
                "author": "bac1",
                "title": "def2",
                "genre": "abc3",
                "price": 9
            }, {
                "author": "bac21",
                "title": "def22",
                "genre": "abc23",
                "price": 8
            }]

        },
        {
            "a1": "b2",
            "book": [{
                "author": "abac",
                "title": "adef",
                "genre": "aabc",
                "price": 165
            }, {
                "author": "baac1",
                "title": "daef2",
                "genre": "aabc3",
                "price": 19
            }, {
                "author": "b4ac21",
                "title": "d4ef22",
                "genre": "a4bc23",
                "price": 7
            }]

        }
    ]
}
```

**Working Script**:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
catalog:
{
    book: flatten(payload.catalog.*book map {
            temp: $ filter ($.price < 10) map {
                autor: $.author,
                title: $.title,
                genre: $.genre,
                price: $.price
            }
    }.temp)
}
```

**Output**:

```
{
  "catalog": {
    "book": [
      {
        "autor": "bac1",
        "title": "def2",
        "genre": "abc3",
        "price": 9
      },
      {
        "autor": "bac21",
        "title": "def22",
        "genre": "abc23",
        "price": 8
      },
      {
        "autor": "b4ac21",
        "title": "d4ef22",
        "genre": "a4bc23",
        "price": 7
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Script with error output**
[image]

Comment: temp: $ filter ($.price < 10) map {  

This line is throwing an error with a red squiggly under the dollar sign that says:  
Expecting Type: `Array<T>`, but got: `{-|author: "Gambarde...scription: String|-}`.
 |-- From: `Array<T>`
 |---- From: filter(items: `Array<T>`, criteria: (item: `T`, index: `Number`) -> `Boolean`) -> `Array<T>`

Comment: Can you paste a sample payload. Is it just one book object that you got under the catalog ?

Comment: If its a list of books that you are trying to transform, i ran the script that i mentioned above in Anypoint studio. Attaching the screenshot for your reference. You can ignore that error indication and studio and should try and execute the script to see if it works. Good luck with the learning and all that is ahead!!

Comment: As well, there happens to be a playground for executing DW scripts outside of the Anypoint Studio. You can try to execute the scripts there, just to confirm the logic and as well helps in learning DataWeave. Its located at. --> dwlang.fun

Comment: Editing my previous comment:  You can ignore the error indication in studio and should try to execute the script (run Mule app)  to see if it works

Comment: @AdrianneGeyer - Did the screenshot and the script mentioned above not help ?

Comment: Thx Salim. Coercing the string to a number worked like a charm!!